# What is a single word for "wandering around a mall or a market"?

Tags: single-word-requests

You know, young girls often do this.

They're wandering around a mall or a supermarket, seeing cute stuff, asking about the prices of things, doing chit-chat with friends, having lunch together with girl friends too, **but end up buying literally nothing**.

Is there a single English word that means this kind of activity?
I can only think of: *hang out*.

Or can *shopping* also mean "buying nothing"?

Comment: Window shopping?

Comment: I googled and found that it is *the activity of looking at the goods displayed in shop windows, esp. without intending to buy anything.* While in my question, it's in a bit broader concept, isn't it? Any other suggestion?

Comment: I suppose it still works, though a lot of franchises in malls tend to be unfenestrated. Here's a more relevant definition: _"Window shopping" is a term referring to the browsing of goods by a consumer with no intent to purchase, either as a recreational activity or to plan a later purchase._ [Wikipedia] Fourth-wall shopping?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Ah, thanks. (y) About fourth-wall shopping, I googled and found nothing about it. Is that a slang? What does it mean, fourth-wall?

Comment: Sorry, Safira  – I was just referring to another thread. Don't expect anyone to have met the term - I doubt that it's ever been used before. The 'fourth wall' is the imaginary one between the actors on a traditional stage and the audience. Or, by extension, between the printed material of a novel, and the reader - etc. 'Breaking' it roughly means getting the audience more than passively involved, so that the fictional material and the audience are no longer totally isolated from each other.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I like *unfenestrated shops.* Or perhaps *shops infenestrate.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [**Browsing**](http://gog.is/define+browsing) - Surveying goods for sale in a leisurely and casual way.
- [**Perusing**](http://gog.is/define+perusing) - Examining carefully or at length.
- [**Window Shopping**](http://gog.is/define+window+shopping) - The activity of looking at goods displayed in shop windows, especially without intending to buy anything.

These could all apply to your situation, depending on what you want to focus on and portray.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think browsing, perusing, or window shopping really do the trick here, because they all imply that the girls are focused on the merchandise, even if they do not intend to buy anything. I'm a child of the 1960s in the US, and as such, I would use the phrase "hanging out." These girls are hanging out at the mall. As I say, that's a very 1960s American youth English kind of phrase, and I cannot guarantee that it translates well to other times or places. I would look it up in the OED and see if there are recent usage examples.

Comment: Uhm, are you saying that my thought *hang out* is correct then?

Comment: Oh, yes...I need to get better and reading the whole question! I did not even see that part. Yes, absolutely, your thought "hang out" is perfect!

Comment: In that case, this a comment not an answer. You're critiquing my answer and agreeing with the OPs original choice, so there is no new answer here.

Comment: Well, Dominic, I see what you mean, but I do not quite agree. My answer is that the questioner's proposed usage, "hang out," is correct.

Comment: I think all four answers have merit. _Browsing, perusing_ and _window shopping_ all work well if the focus of the activity is, say, looking at clothes – as would _looking around_. (Clerk: _"Can I help you find something?"_ Heather: _"No thanks, we're just looking around."_) However, _hanging out_ might work better if the primary focus is spending time together, it just happens to be at the mall. (Monica: _"What did girls you do last week?_" Heather: _"Thursday we hung out at Julia's house; Friday we hung out at the mall."_) @Dominic - This isn't a "critique", but it does fill in some holes.

Comment: @J.R. 'Seeing cute stuff, asking about the price of things' does sound to me like *perusing* and I think this is more focused and eloquent than *hanging out*. That said, I may have taken a defensive approach due to the wording of this answer. An answer that begins by criticising another answer begins with a negative tone, Micheal you could've applied a bit more tact. S'all good. :)

Comment: @Dominic - As for the proper focus, I think _perusing_ indeed focuses on shopping, as you say, but _hanging out_ focuses on "doing chit-chat with friends, having lunch together" and _meandering_ focuses on "wandering around a mall or a supermarket." In my opinion, that makes all answers here quite valid – although, of the three, your answer could probably benefit the most from a bit more elaboration, i.e., something a bit more than a bare bones "come to mind."

Comment: @J.R. fair point, I've been on a mobile all day, I will add links and examples when I'm on my laptop. I, personally, would've left this answer as a comment, but that's just me.

Comment: True, the first part of this answer could have been left as a comment. I didn't read it as an outright rejection of your answer, though, I felt your answer was being used as a springboard. To paraphrase: "_Window-shopping_ addresses the part about looking at merchandise, but the O.P. seems to be asking about more – not just perusing the aisles, but walking from store to store, eating, etc." This is a great example of an ELU question where the whole group of answers is worth more than the sum of the parts. Yes, we **can** shop and buy nothing, esp. when we meander, windowshop, and hang out. :^)

Comment: @J.R.: Does this mean that all the answers are all right? Honestly IDK which single word should I put in mind. There are a lot of answer and I can't choose which one since IDK what it is. Need more help.

Comment: @Safira - It means all the answers satisfy your request in one way or another, but they emphasize different parts of your request. A question like yours is unlikely to have one correct answer, or a single legitimate answer. The Stack Exchange isn't set up to let you choose more than one answer, so the best you can do is upvote all of them, and choose one. If you want more advice about what to do next, I suggest reading through the suggestions at [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17257).

Comment: @Dominic Gotcha about the negative tone and tact. I come out of a Socratic academic tradition, maybe similar to the high school debate team, where vigorous and outspoken disagreement is part of the process, and need not be taken personally (unless it's clear that the opponent is being malicious). That being said, I'm a newbie here, and I'm still learning the etiquette. Cheers!

Comment: @MochealBroder I understand, and it's easy to misconstrue the tone of an argument when its written in plain text. I apologise if I came across in a rude way. Welcome to StackExchange. :)

Answer (score 3):

**malling**

*the action or activity of passing time in a shopping mall* ([**oxforddictionaries.com**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/malling))

*going to the mall with a large group of people with no intention of buying anything.* ([**urbandictionary.com**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Malling))

Answer (score 2):

*Pottering* is a good one: occupy oneself in a desultory but pleasant way.

> "I'm quite happy just to potter about by myself here."

Comment: I hadn't heard this variant of _putter_ so I initially assumed it was a typo. Interesting to learn this – thanks for the post!

Comment: I know, it's really fascinating to learn the differences between US and UK language. I actually live in Australia, but I abide by Uk English rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Meandering**:

> following a winding course.

as in:

> The girls meandered through the mall, chatting and window shopping, without buying a thing.

Comment: "Meander" is nice. For that matter, "wander" is nice. But I think the OP was looking for an expression, like "hanging out," that suggests more-or-less innocent loitering, using the mall as a social gathering location rather than as a place to buy anything.

Comment: @Safira - The word is sometimes used to describe a river that isn't straight, and is also used to describe people that seem to be wandering around without much direction or purpose. It's not all that uncommon a word – [here are some examples](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+girls+meandered%22&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=Mp13UsyFEuPksAS0loCwBQ&ved=0CAwQ_AUoBA&biw=1467&bih=848).

Comment: The word *meander* means to weave left and right sporadically. If you meandered through the mall, you'd look like you were drunk.